# Anti-Derivative where f(n) = m

Tags: calculus

I'm studying for my final tomorrow, and have the question:

A function f defined for all real numbers satisfies: $f'(1)=1$, $f(0)=4$, and $f''(x)=12x^2-12x$. Find the value of $f(2)$.

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer or not, I missed the lectures about anti-derivatives,

$$f''(x)=12x^2-12x$$
$$f'(x)=4x^3-6x^2+C, C=3$$
$$f(x)=x^4-2x^3+C, C=4$$

$$f(2)=(2)^4-2(2)^3+C$$
$$=16-16+C$$
$$C, C=4$$
$$4$$

Comment: Almost had it. When you take the antiderivative of a constant $C$ (with respect to $x$), you end up with $Cx+D$, where $D$ is another constant. You should plug in for your constants along the way once you've solved for them. So the first derivative becomes $f'(x)=4x^3 - 6x^2 + 3$. Then take the antiderivative of that and find the new constant based on the initial values.

Comment: According to the original post, $f'(1)=1$, so $C=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct, but you are close. After you figure out C in the second line ($f'(x)=4x^3-6x^2+C, C=3$), you have to plug in the value of C to the equation. Then when you take the anti-derivative again, you must do it for the value of C as well. In this example, $f(x)=x^4-2x^3+C$ should be $f(x)=x^4-2x^3+3x+C$.

Note that the C's between the equations are not the same.